# What happens if two wolf kills are targeted to a huntsman's target?

Tags: werewolv.es

If two wolves try to attack a target guarded by the Huntsman (e.g. the wolves have a Bloodthirster), what happens to the wolves killing?

Would both wolves die or is it random as to who dies?

Answer (score 1):

Both wolves would die in this scenario. Any other attackers from other factions that are vulnerable to the Huntsman's defence would also be killed. Vulnerable attackers include Warlocks, Ghouls and Voodoo Doctors. The Huntsman also would protect against an additional Vampire attack, but the Vampire would not be killed by the confrontation.

This is because when the morning starts attacks are resolved "simultaneously" - as the game acquires more interactions this may not be desirable anymore, but it certainly isn't changing in the short term.